# Push Notifications with RealmDB (MongoDB) and react-native-push-notification

Tags: mongodb, firebase, react-native, realm, react-native-push-notification

I am using Realm for an already quite elaborate application and I want to finish it by adding push notifications. I have already installed react-native-push-notification and make it works with FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

On the client side, I do receive test notifications from Firebase.

[image: Firebase console]
[image: Client side]

I then configured the push notifications in the Realm console by adding the Sender Id and the API Key.

[image: Realm console]

The problem is that when I send a notification from Realm it ends up in "sent", but absolutely nothing happens, no logs in the Realm console, nothing on the Firebase side and nothing on the client side.

[image: Push notifications (Realm)]

The documentation on push notifications for Realm is really limited and I can't quite figure out what to do. The documentation is mainly directed for IOS and Android.

That's my code in index.js:

```js
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

PushNotification.configure({
  onRegister: function (token) {
    console.log('TOKEN:', token);
  },
  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
  },

  onAction: function (notification) {
    console.log('ACTION:', notification.action);
    console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
  },

  onRegistrationError: function (err) {
    console.error(err.message, err);
  },
  permissions: {
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  },
  popInitialNotification: true,
  requestPermissions: true,
});

PushNotification.createChannel(
  {
    channelId: 'fcm_fallback_notification_channel',
    channelName: 'FCM CHANNEL',
    channelDescription: 'Description test',
  },
  created => console.log(`CreateChannel returned '${created}'`),
);

PushNotification.localNotification({
  channelId: 'fcm_fallback_notification_channel',
  vibrate: true,
  vibration: 300,
  playSound: true,
  soundName: 'default',
});
```

Does anyone know of a tutorial or something that could give me some additional information?

Comment: Careful about asking for tutorials here on SO. That would generally get the question closed as (from the SO Docs) *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam*. It's also not clear what's being asked; if you're using Firebase Notifications and it's working, what else do you need? Why don't you just use Firebase for that functionality?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

My database is on MongoDB and it's using Realm, so I need to send notifications related to changes in my database in RealmDB / MongoDB.

Firebase Cloud Messaging become just a service for sending push notifications triggered by Realm when it is needed.

And asking for a tutorial is needed here, because it's totally impossible to find one for making push notifications works between Realm and Firebase through React Native... So the "spam" or "opinionated answers" should be very rare.

Comment: Just trying to prevent the question from being closed. Firebase and Realm are totally unrelated and there is nothing that ties them together. You would have to add an observer to your Realm database that then triggers a Firebase cloud function to post a notification. But again, those are unrelated technologies that you would need to craft the code to link them together.

Comment: Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to make it work, you'll have to add this line in index.js:

```js
PushNotification.subscribeToTopic('topic-id-in-realm-console');
```

And use the same topic id in Realm console:

[image: realm console topic id]

It ends up with something like this (index.js):

```js
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

PushNotification.configure({
  onRegister: function (token) {
    console.log('TOKEN:', token);
  },

  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
  },

  onAction: function (notification) {
    console.log('ACTION:', notification.action);
    console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
  },

  onRegistrationError: function (err) {
    console.error(err.message, err);
  },

  permissions: {
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  },
  popInitialNotification: true,
  requestPermissions: true,
});

PushNotification.subscribeToTopic('topic-id-in-realm-console');// <== HERE
```

On client:

[image]